# Stop Visual Studio sending debug console to background

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core

Create a dotnet Console app in Visual Studio. Hit run in debug (F5) the console starts and remains "in front of" Visual Studio.

Create a AspeNetCore app and debug with one of the http/https profiles (never use iisexpress, usually delete it from launchSettings).
In this case the console is sent to the far background. In order to bring it forward you just alt-tab (a lot, cos it is sent all the way to the back), or find it on the task bar.

I would *really* like the console to stay "on top" in the same way the Console App does.
I suspect this is related to how VS handles "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" type projects, but got very lost in that rabbit hole.

I have tried to programmatically bring the console to the foreground. This works if the window is placed behind anything other than VS (set break point, then find and drag console behind something on a different screen). If it left behind VS (VS always starts it this way) then the "SetForegroundWindow" command effectively does nothing.

I am hoping there is an option for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you can directly display the console window in front of Visual Studio through the settings of Visual Studio.

1. Right-click your project in Solution Explorer, click Properties=>Debug=>General=>open debug launch profiles UI=>Uncheck the option box under launch browser

[image]

2. Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>ASP.NET Core=>Set 'Launch external console minimized' to false

[image]

The effect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: "Launch Browser" makes no difference to the state of the console.
"Launch external console minimised" is exactly what I was looking for
@wenbingeng-MSFT THANK YOU